# Fixing terrible performance when watching/reading video and writing video files to disk

Tags: performance, disk-usage

I have had this issue for quite some time and tried many times to fix it on my own and it always fails.  IP schedulers, ionice and things like that always yield no result. I even went and bought an ssd thinking maybe it would fix the issue.  Nope.

The issue is we have a fairly powerful workstation that has data being downloaded to a single disk on it at a rate of about 10-15MB/s consistently.  Most of these need to be screened so they tend to be watched as the data is being written to the disk.  The performance is atrocious. Audio goes out of sync, large videos fail to load, video will just stop while audio keeps going, corruption.  But when you stop the data transfer all is fine.

I opened up iotop and yes the download the writing a lot but the videos even large videos really don't seem to be reading all that much.

I have tried different io schedulers, I have tried ionice, I have tried nice, I have tried buying an ssd to see if the increased performance somehow fixes it!  But nope. I have tried different video players like mplayer and vlc. I have tried configuring them to take on more cache so they read ahead and rely on the disk less but nothing works.

It's becoming a really big problem.

The video playing needs to be the priority when it's playing and the data writing should yield.  So when the video is being watched the download can be slowed down or the write can be slowed but not overall.

I hope somebody has some ideas.

> %Cpu(s): 23.5 us,  5.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 59.1 id, 10.8 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.0
>   si,  0.0 st

Comment: How fast is the workstation's network connection and how much bandwidth is the workstation using while downloading and viewing?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick the workstation has a gigabit lan connection.  The wan connection is 100Mbit.  So we consistently download full speed at around 14MB/s.

Comment: Just to make it clear: the stream is written uninterruptedly and at the same time it is *usually*  watched at the same time?

Comment: Do you know how much free memory you have? If the download is an async write then that might be delaying the video application from buffering enough of the video in memory. Also, how did you zero in on disk I/O versus the CPU?

Comment: Another alternative would to be launch whatever process is downloading the videos and use cgroups to throttle disk io at that level.

Comment: I would personally suspect the video card being the potential bottle neck, especially if you are using an on-board CPU GPU (such as those that ship with modern Intel chips). Because the CPU is spending a lot of time servicing the interrupts for the disk I/O, it will have an impact on the performance of the internal GPUs ability to decode/render the video. You are going to need to investigate the utilization (with such tools as top) to see where the video viewing software is bound (in system, user or in wait). My guess will be on the former or latter.

Comment: @peterph Yep you got it.

Comment: @Bratchley For your first: I am doing it right now watching a conference.  My system has a total of 8GB of memory.  907M of it is unallocated while 6428M is marked under the free/cache column.  So it doesn't seem to be a memory issue.  Lots of free memory.

In top "wa" jumps around a lot. Usually around .3 but I can see it now as high as 47 at one point but usually below 10.0.  Here's a snapshot.


%Cpu(s): 23.5 us,  5.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 59.1 id, 10.8 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.0 si,  0.0 st

Comment: @Bratchley I'll look into cgroups.  They are new to me. I have heard of them before just not much experience.

Comment: @DravSloan Hi,

Here's a view of the interups while playing the video while downloading 

%Cpu(s): 23.5 us,  5.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 59.1 id, 10.8 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.0 si,  0.0 st

I have a pretty good video card using vdpau.  I have an nvidia 750 Ti.  So while it's not top of the line it's the newest chipset and all.

Comment: If you're getting high iowait [you might look into cgroups](http://kaivanov.blogspot.com/2012/07/setting-up-linux-cgroups-control-groups.html) and either lower the priority for the downloading program or use a script to temporarily throttle back bps for the times you launch `vlc`

Comment: @Bratchley ionice doesn't do this at all? I know it doesn't use cgroups.

Comment: @Biff so certainly not a GPU bottle neck. So your usage stats show that most of the CPU is bound in user processes and I/O wait (in my experience the higher wait percentage you have the poorer the response from the CPU). If the decoding of the videos is not handled by your GPU, then again you are falling back on the CPU to provide that process. Have you tried streaming the video to another PC/server, to rule out CPU choking of the servers CPU?

Comment: `ionice` is only relevant for the the cfq I/O scheduler. Other schedulers ignore it. It carves up I/O time in a similar way that the regular `nice` command carves up CPU time. Meaning it's more or less a rough suggestion to carve up overall throughput. I would at least try cgroups, they're not that difficult and they give you more to throttle on that just the process ID.

Comment: Just to test I would set wildly different priorities on the two applications, and then just modify the I/O priority until your priority for the download is as high as it can get while still guaranteeing I/O bandwidth for the video application.

Comment: What OS/Distribution is this on, BTW? I guess I just assumed Linux without verifying that was the case.

Comment: As for media players VLC is (in my experience) much heavier then the mplayer line. As for `mplayer` and forks I find the original performs better. (Note that e.g. Debian (and derivatives only have `mplayer2` as package (at least for now)), which, at least here perform worse. Another fork is `mpv`. But then again I have a crappy video card. It would at least be a point in ensuring the various players actually are using `vdpau`. (But guess you have made sure of this?) It varies what and how good the different players utilize vdpau as well.

Comment: how are you actually playing the stream? Are you writing it to the disk and then playing it *from* the disk almost immediately?

Comment: You should switch to a different bus. If you've got all of the i/o going through a single channel - say two hdds on a single SATA controller, or - worse, one hdd on a single SATA channel - then you'll probably want to vary throughput. Maybe get a USB 3.0 disk and watch put the video you want to watch on there - or - better - another SATA controller or whatever. Just try multiple paths, basically.

Comment: Sorry guys had to step out.

@DravSloan I could try streaming to my tablet. I never really thought of that. You are right vdpau does not work for all codecs.

Comment: @Bratchley I am on Ubuntu 14.04 all up to date.  I will give the cgroups a try. I don't know for sure if it will be tonight as I have some prep for a meeting tomorrow to do.  I will try as it looks like the most promising lead yet.   Thanks for the info on schedulers.  I didn't know that.

Comment: @user367890 I tend to verify that vdpau is working by looking at top/htop and making sure the cpu utilization is low for the players process.  If it is then I just assume it is.  As for mplayer I have user smplayer front end before. It was a bit delicate though.

Comment: @peterph The files are just played from disk.  They sit there for a very long time sometimes before they are watched.  The issue occurs if the file is just downloaded or has been sitting there for weeks.

Comment: @mikeserv Yeah that is a fair point but that also doubles the storage and makes things a bit more messy to keep track of.  Not a major issue though.  Most of these all go over the south bridge so wouldn't that too just be saturated just the same.

Comment: Maybe so - that's where the superio lives - but if so then you'll want a new motherboard. Of course, it is a lot more likely that a single disk *(or controller)* would swamp before the whole systems bus does. And plugging a portable hdd in - even just a borrowed one - to test the theory is probably going to be much less expensive as well. And by the way - if it really is all on a single disk - then the builtin firmware/controller of the disk itself then the disk's builtin controller and cache make for even smaller channels than any of the rest.

Comment: One thing that might help a bit (to much less extent if you are already hitting a hardware limit somewhere) is tuning the file system (or even moving to another one). Have you tried enabling player caching?

Comment: @Biff out of curiosity did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the VM subsystem hints? POSIX fadvise that is? You may find that the download process is trashing your VM cache.  Download linux-ftools and wrap the download/write to disk script with fadvise dontneed and see what happens. https://code.google.com/p/linux-ftools/

Comment: If you have source code access to the downloader, see whether using memory mapped files would help. I'd try: 1. Use the deadline scheduler. 2. Try to bunch up your writes into few large consecutive writes instead of many small writes (IOPS vs Throughput). 3. Tell your downloader to stop abusing  the vm cache (posix fadvise). 4. ionice the downloader to a lower priority and the reader process to a higher priority. 5. Have a look at /prov/sys/vm/[dirty-ratio, dirty_bytes]. Playing with this variable will influence your writeback behaviour. http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_vm_dirty_bytes.html